# What's a more appropriate word than verbatim or literal in this context?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, synonyms, expression-choice

> The XML file is being transcribed *verbatim* to generate the form on the web page.

Perhaps *literal* fits better than *verbatim*, as the former denotes a looser correlation (in my opinion) than the latter, or maybe I'm just splitting hairs.  Either way, neither of these really conveys my intended message.  I'm looking for a word or expression that conveys an exact 1:1 correlation between everything in A and everything in B, but B is not actually a "word for word" copy of A.  A and B don't have to be XML and a web page.  You can think of them like apples and oranges.  If you were going to generate an orange based on an apple (whatever that means), and every aspect of the apple would be reflected in an aspect of the orange that was generated...how would you describe the precision of that transcription or translation process?

*I apologize if there are any issues with this question, or it is inappropriate for this stack exchange - this is my first time posting on this stack exchange.*

Comment: "Literal" could not be placed in your sentence directly in place of verbatim: "The XML file is being transcribed *literal* to generate the form on the web page." is not a good sentence.

Comment: How can a 1 to 1 mapping be other than verbatim? Anything less would be a paraphrase. The formatting doesn't need to be exactly the same (different fonts may be used etc).

Comment: You are probably referring to a  *conversion* : something that is changed from one use, function, or purpose to another.

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, I could use conversion in place of transcription or translation perhaps, but I'm looking for a better word to describe the precision of that conversion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's not a paraphrase.  All information is carried from A to B.  But the form changes, so it's not "word for word".  A "hello" in group A might translate into a hand wave in group B for example.  But for every "hello" in A there is a hand wave in B.

Comment: Ah, you're going outside of the rendering of English script  A to English script B; this now becomes subject-specific and perhaps off-topic. The mathematician would call a 1 to 1 functional mapping an injective mapping.

Comment: *precisely*?  If that's not it, could you please expand your question.  I keep feeling like I'm *almost* getting your idea.

Comment: perhaps **scrupulously** or **accurately**

Comment: How about "functionally equivalent"?  Two versions of XML might differ in areas that don't affect the output of  a rendering agent.  They thus wouldn't be identical, but would be functionally equivalent.

Comment: The problem is that you haven't described the entities that are being transferred. In language you would be translating *words*. In data-processing you would be transforming *data*, etc. What are you shifting?  What does it start as and what does it finish as? Symbols? Bytes?

Comment: @deadrat: "functionally equivalent" may be suitable. But as other proposals (mine included), its more or less a as a pleonasm with "transcribed"

Comment: @Graffito Yeah, transcribed can't be used here because it already has the connotation of direct reporting.  Eric is going to have to find another trans- word that suits his application -- transformed, transmitted, translated, etc.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the XML file is being translated literally to generate the form on the web page.  (As @Catija pointed out, the adjective "literal" won't work here, but I think the adverb "literally" works well.)

Comment: @deadrat +1 just for exposing me to the word "pleonasm"!  I don't necessarily agree that "functionally equivalent" is a pleonasm for "transcribed" in this situation (if I'm understanding the definition of pleonasm correctly), as I don't think "transcribed" really conveys the "conversion" that takes place when you represent a set of data as something else entirely, such as a set of interactive web controls adjustable values.

Comment: @deadrat As for "functionally equivalent" itself, that is a very good answer, and for the layman perhaps the best way to describe it.  But I think something along the lines of "injective mapping" is more precise in technical terms.

Comment: If you are wanting to explain this to a non-techie, I'd use "as is," i.e. The XML file is transcribed as is to generate the form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that "injective mapping", or something that it lead me to, such as "monomorphism", is exactly what I was looking for - precise, concise, and technically accurate.  If you put that in an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics, a relation between the elements in a starting set (the domain, the set of input items) and those in a target set (the codomain) is said to be injective (one-to-one) if every element of the codomain is mapped to by at most one element of the domain. If every element of the codomain is mapped to by exactly one element of the domain, the function is bijective. {[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection)}

This can be applied in various situations: mapping numbers to their doubles; mapping dogs to their owners (here, depending on the starting sets, not all mappings will be surjections!); mapping letters to their coded substitutes in a simple substitution cipher ...